# Deploy in projet with DeployBundle

Tags: symfony, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy one in my project with DeployBundle and made the following settings:

parameter.yml

```
jordi_llonch_deploy:
    config:
        project: delivve
        vcs: git
        servers_parameter_file: app/config/parameters_deployer_servers.yml
        local_repository_dir: /home/deploy/local_repository
        clean_max_deploys: 7
        ssh:
            proxy: cli
            user: user
            password: 'password'
            public_key_file: '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'
            private_key_file: '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa'
            private_key_file_pwd: 'password'
    zones:
        prod_myproj:
            deployer: delivve
            environment: prod
            checkout_url: 'https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project-webservice.git'
            checkout_branch: master
            repository_dir: /var/www/production/delivve/deploy
            production_dir: /var/www/production/delivve/code
```

parameters_deployer_servers.yml

```
prod_myproj:
    urls:
        - user@localhost:22
```

It has also the service and the setting but it seems this working out that part.

My problem is when I give the command:

```
sudo php app/console deployer:initialize --zones=prod_myproj
```

of the following error:

```
[prod_myproj]
[2016-01-04 18:25:55] app.CRITICAL: Not implemented  
ROLLBACK [prod_myproj]
[2016-01-04 18:25:55] app.CRITICAL: Not implemented
```

Anyone know what can this happening, and how could solve, or to deploy with this bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like comming from the password authentication (https://github.com/jordillonch/DeployBundle/blob/3f8e679eb2ac87d0cef9ea9dd4765afd24c6a266/SSH/CLISshProxy.php#L60).

Try removing `jordi_llonch_deploy.config.ssh.password` from your `config.yml` (https://github.com/jordillonch/DeployBundle/blob/3f8e679eb2ac87d0cef9ea9dd4765afd24c6a266/SSH/SshClient.php#L76).